# TK, understanding pack and expanding space

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a window that is resizeable, where i want to have two listboxes with scroll bars that expand to fill all space available.

when i have only one listbox packed as `fill=both, expand=1, side=left` and one scrollbar packed as `fill=Y, expand=0, side=right` then it will expand only horizontally, even though it is set to fill both directions. when i resize the window, the listbox only fill the sides. the bottom of the window remain empty.

[image]

then i moved on to add another listbox. Now instead of packing the scroll bar on right, i packed everything to left, so they are stacked. the listboxes continue to have `fill=both, expand=1`. Now when i resize the window both list boxes only fill vertically! the horizontal space remains empty.

[image]

what is going on? why does it ignore the vertical space with one element packed left and another right? and why it refuses to fill horizontally when everything is stacked left?

the fact that once it fill the vertical or the horizontal space leads me to believe the parent frame is expanding fine... or should i investigate that more as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your actual code it's impossible to know what you're doing wrong. Here's an example to prove that `pack` works as documented:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
lb1 = tk.Listbox(root)
lb2 = tk.Listbox(root)
vsb1 = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=lb1.yview)
vsb2 = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=lb2.yview)
lb1.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb1.set)
lb2.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb2.set)

lb1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
vsb1.pack(side="left", fill="y", expand=False)
lb2.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
vsb2.pack(side="left", fill="y", expand=False)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ha! while adapting your code to add a parent `Frame`, just to be sure, i made the mistake of not changing the parent of the listboxes from root to the new frame, and obviously the empty space of the expanding frame was what i was seeing... and sure enough, that was the mistake i think i did on my code before.

Answer (score 0):

workaround i'm using (downvote if not the right tk way)

i created two frames, both `side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH` and then put each pair of listbox+scrollbar there. now everything expands/fills just fine.

[image]
previously the listboxes were in the yellow frame. The ones i just created are the the blue and green.

still not sure with the pack manager would not expand the listboxes when they had scrollbars without expansion between them...